# better/quicker way of summing up CSV key:value data

Tags: python

I'm currently running into a bottleneck while trying to do some stuff with CSV files.

They are very simple CSV files like this:

```
SKU; Value
sku1; 1
sku1; 3
sku2; 3
sku3; 4
sku3; 1
```

I'm currently importing them into a list of Objects

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, SKU, value):
        self.SKU = SKU
        self.value = value
```

And then I sum the values to find the total for a given SKU as so:

```
def sum_data(csvdata):
    newData = [] #We are going to store the correct data here.
        for row in csvdata:
            rowNums = [i for i, x in enumerate(csvdata) if x.SKU == row.SKU] # Find if there's multiple SKU in the list.
            if len(rowNums) > 1: # We sum all the values if theres more than 1
                row_iterator = iter(rowNums)
                next(row_iterator)
                for index in row_iterator:
                    row.value += csvdata[index].value
                
            if not any(x.SKU == row.SKU for x in newData): # If the SKU is not yet in the new list, we add it.
                newData.append(row)

    return newData
```

While I can improve the loop code (its currently a simple and unoptimized, i should check if the SKU exists in newData first, which will help a lot), I was wondering if there was any easy way and/or framework to work with this data. I know there's really lovely frameworks like Pandas and numpy but I've never used them and don't know where to start.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: "...but I've never used them and don't know where to start". A good starting point is putting "Python Pandas Tutorial" into a search engine.

Comment: I currently don't have enough time to soak up all of pandas and learn "from scratch" - I need some indications on what's going to be useful for this case. Learning it properly is in my bucket list but not something I can currently rush through @dfundako

Comment: No need for hyperbole. No one is suggesting you soak it all up or formally learn it. Take 5 seconds and Google "Pandas sum values from csv"